# C stack memory dump, why does the first argument appear twice?

Tags: c, stack, arguments, variadic-functions

I was experimenting with the address space of the stack in C and found something that made me lift my eyebrows. The following code snippet calls a function which in turn prints out the integer values of the memory starting with the address of the first argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void func(int arg, int second, ...) {
    int i=0;
    for (; i < 20; i++) {
        int* addr = &arg + i;
        printf("* %d\n", *addr);
    }
}

int main() {
    func(42, 67, 24, 92);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
* 42           <
* 1075105048
* -1081967932
* 1073841448
* -16121856
* 1075105060
* 1073828160
* -1081967880
* 134513921
* 42           <
* 67           <
* 24           <
* 92           <
* 134513984
* 0
* -1081967880
* 134513529
* -16121856
* -1081967856
* -1081967816
```

Now, what makes me suspicious are the lines I marked with a `<` sign. The four elements in a row are equal to the arguments I passed to the function. But why is the value first argument appearing twice in the output?

Is there a standardized memory layout for the arguments passed to a C function, or is the implementation of `stdarg.h` extremely compiler dependent?

Comment: It's extremely compiler dependent.

Comment: If you really want to do this sort of thing, look at the generated assembly instead.  And yes, it is compiler (and compiler flags) dependent.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks! Yet, I'm wondering why the `42` appears twice. Any idea?

Comment: You're actually invoking undefined behavior by even looking at the stack like that.  So unless you ask regarding a specific C compiler on a specific platform, why it happens is unanswerable and irrelevant.  It'd be like asking "why does the byte at 0x40220558 have this particular value?"; it'd require knowing the OS and seeing the assembler code, at least.

Comment: `...` is called `ellipsis operator` and its ability to decode what you are passing to it depends on the compiler type system, so its behaviour is basically non-standard.

Comment: 42 is the answer to life the universe and everything ... that's why it prints probably.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the assembler directly would be a better way to go around this but I think the reason for seeing 42 twice is an artefact of the way st compilers will implement the stack. Mostly the stack starts at a high location in memory and grows down. So your function is going to store the arguments in a stack frame below the frame for the main function. You then print from the address of the first argument upwards. So you get the first argument followed by the start of the stack frame followed by some of the main stack frame which will include the arguments that are passed to your function. So that is why you see 42 twice.
Of course this line of argument assumed that the compiler and OS are working in a certain way. As I said already, looking at the assembly will give you a much more accurate picture.